# How can I build a version of utop that uses the native toplevel ocamlnat?

Tags: ocaml, utop

ocamlnat is distributed with the compiler but not built by default. I can only start it by typing `make natruntop` in the ocaml compiler build directory. How can I make this into a fully functional native utop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a big amount of work to do. The `ocamlnat` project is still a bit of experimental and not officially distributed. There is an [ongoing work](https://gitlab.camlcity.org/gerd/ocamlnat), to revive it. What concerning binding it to `utop` then it would be a separate big amount of work, that will involve some programming. But it is too preliminary to speak about this at this stage of the project.

Note: `utop` is not just a wrapper around OCaml toplevel, it is a separate implementation, so retargeting it to a new backend, might not be that easy.

Comment: ok. my question was prompted by this comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ocaml/comments/3qjs1q/utop_is_a_much_better_toplevel_than_ocaml_if_you/cwh1cb0 where somebody claims to have done it!

Comment: anyway, cool that this seems to be coming. an opam package for native utop at some point would be cool for interactive statistics etc.

Comment: yeah, I'm also waiting eagerly for this to happen!